# draw outside on-draw method in android canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I want draw text and lines in a particular canvas from outside on-draw method is there any way to draw .
for example .in my case

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}

draw()
{
    /***  my drawing stuff ***/
}
```

Suggest some example code to get rid out of this error

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: suggest me some alternative for this problem

Comment: draw everything in onDraw method, whats wrong with that?

Comment: i want to draw during run time in a certain condition.

Comment: so add that condition in onDraw and invalidate the view

Answer (score 0):

create some String objects and set their values. and in the end call `invalidate()` on the view.

```
String text;
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
  {

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, mPaint);//this will draw what text's current value is
   }


public void draw(){
text="yr text";//change the value 
invalidate();//this will refresh the view.
}
```

You can also look at surface view. Which is more suitable for such requirements.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: i cant get it ...little bit explain for me ...im new to android

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the drawing on an offscreen bitmap and than in the `OnDraw` call only update the canvas with that bitmap.

It will be something like this.

```
public void drawShape(){
    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmapOffscreen);

    // all draw calls can be placed here or any other method
    // e.g.
    mCanvas.drawColor(0xaaaaaa);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(500, 500);
    path.quadTo(150, 150, 30, 10);
    mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}

// after all above invalidate() will eventually call onDraw()
// this will put your offscreen bitmap on the view
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mCanvas = canvas;

    if (mBitmap != null) {
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapOffscreen, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must use the `onDraw()` method to get a *Canvas*.  And you need a *Canvas* to pretty much do anything.

You may be tempted to save the canvas to some higher level variable and use it later.  But that could lead to some unexpected behavior that is very difficult to debug.  So unless you're Romain Guy, don't even try (and I *know* he won't do it!).

And yes, it is a **total pain in the ass** to have to make a subclass of a widget, override the `onDraw()` method, and put in this mess just to do something ONCE!  But that's the world we live it; that's how event-driven programming works.

Here's a quick version:

**[file MyButton.java]**

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    public boolean myOneTimeConditionIsTrue = false; // will be set true when the condition is just right

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (myOneTimeConditionIsTrue) {
            myOneTimedrawStuff(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void myOneTimedrawStuff(Canvas canvas) {
        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

Then you have to change your XML so that it uses your NEW widget instead of the usual suspects.

**[file my_layout.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mypackage.MyButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click me"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Yes, it's a lot of work, but you'll get used to it. And if there's an easier way to do this, I'd love to hear about it.